# Why can I not embed a string literal inside an f-string?

Tags: python, f-string

Code:

```python
tinydict = {'Name': 'Runoob', 'Age': 27}
# print ("Age : %s" %  tinydict.get('Age')) # can display correctly
print(f'Age : {tinydict.get('Age')}')
```

Output:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Why?

Comment: Also, please use an editor that highlights syntax – you would have seen the problem right away.

Comment: @AKX I wouldn’t be so sure. Stack Overflow’s own highlighter doesn’t get this one right.

Comment: @user3840170 Well, my PyCharm is smarter than SO's highlighter, anyway... https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4hVK.png

Comment: That's btw the previous question for the `f-string` tag right before yours. Did you not check it or do you consider your question really different?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use something other than single quotes in the field.

```
print(f'Age : {tinydict.get("Age")}')
```

As a string literal, the entire expression has to be recognized during lexical analysis, and the lexical analyzer isn't sophisticated enough to start a new quoting "context" when it sees the `{`. As a result, it sees

```
f'Age {tinydict.get('
```

as a complete string literal, followed by the identifier `tinydict`, which produces the syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

[PEP 498 explains](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/#escape-sequences):

> Due to Python’s string tokenizing rules, the f-string `f'abc {a['x']} def'` is invalid. The tokenizer parses this as 3 tokens: `f'abc {a['`, `x`, and `']} def'`. Just like regular strings, this cannot be fixed by using raw strings. There are a number of correct ways to write this f-string: with a different quote character:
>
> ```python
> f"abc {a['x']} def"
> ```
>
> Or with triple quotes:
>
> ```python
> f'''abc {a['x']} def'''
> ```

The grammar followed by the tokenizer is [explained in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).  As you can see, at the lexing stage the parser does not attempt to tell whether a quote character might belong to some nested string.  It just finds the first non-escaped sequence that matches the opening quote and considers that the end of the string.

Put another way, the Python parser first determines where the boundaries of the f-string are, and only later proceeds to parse the expressions embedded inside.